# Update JOIN table contents

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table joined from two other tables. I would like this table to stay updated with entries in the other two tables.

First Table is "employees"

I am using the ID, Last_Name, and First_Name.

And the second Table is "EmployeeTimeCardActions"

using columns ID, ActionTime, ActionDate, ShiftStart, and ActionType.

ID is my common column that the join was created by..[Joined Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQkDk.png)...

Because I usually have a comment saying I did not include enough information, I do not need a exact specific code sample and I think I have included everything needed. If there is a good reason to include more I will, I just try to keep as little company information public as possible

Comment: I see you already joined your tables, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Your question is not clear  .. youn should update you question adding a proper data sample ..  your actual code .. you actual result and your expected  result ...  not post image (only) post the sample and the code as text

Comment: You need code for the part that's already done?  Is it not just a simple update statement that someone can point out? Table is already joined. Does the update command belong in that code?

Comment: Again like I typed out in the question. I am looking for direction not the code to make it work. If it belongs in the JOIN statement then I will look at that. If not then maybe I can use a little direction, but then my supplied information is enough. You have column and table names code doesn't change for these things overnight. You should be able to put 2 and 2 together if I can, especially if this is only my 2nd time even looking at SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're having your data duplicated across tables. Not a smart idea at all. You can update data in one table when a row is updated in a different one via triggers but this is a TERRIBLE approach. If you want to display data joined from 2 tables, the right approach here is using an SQL VIEW which will display the current data.